# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Query questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've implemented "following" function. Showing "people user A is following" was simple, but showing "people who are following user A" is giving me troubles.

I have follow_links, which have id, user_id, and follow_you_id column. When user A begins following user B, the columns will be like (user_id = A, follow_you_id = B).

To show users that A(@user) is following, I can simply do

```
@follow_yous = @user.follow_yous
```

But I'm not sure how to show users who are following A(@user)

To do this, I first found all the related links.

```
@follow_links = FollowLink.where(:follow_you_id => @user.id)
```

Now I thought I could just do `@follow_mes = @follow_links.users`, but it says `user` is an undefined method. So I guess I can either call `user.follow_yous` or `follow_you.users`.

My next approach was

```
@follow_links = FollowLink.where(:follow_you_id => @user.id)
@follow_mes = User.where(:id => @user.id, :include => @follow_links)
```

I intended to find all the User objects that had the provided @follow_links objects, but I think the syntax was wrong. I couldn't find a decent solution after a bit of research. I'd appreciate any help.

**Update:
FollowLink model**

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follow_you, :class_name => "User"
```

Comment: What does your `FollowLink` model look like? You have to set up the relation to two different kinds of users (followers and followees) there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) like this:

```
@users = User.joins(:follow_links).where(:follow_links => { :follow_you_id => @user.id })
```

Comment: Thank you. this works very well. Could you explain it a bit for me though? This means that user.follow_links would call right objects. Then how come follow_link.users doesn't call users?

Comment: @MaximusS, because `User has_many :follow_links`, but `FollowLink belongs_to :user`. This means you can only do `follow_link.user`, but not `follow_link.users`. You have to write a specific query like above to get the info you want. It is not supported out-of-the-box by ActiveRecord.

Comment: You mean `user.follow_links` is only allowed, right? I'm not confused anymore. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, because of the `has_many`, `user.follow_links` is valid. You're welcome.

Comment: One more question to add: then how does post.user work if user has_many posts, and post belongs_to user?

Comment: @MaximusS: a post belongs to a user, so `post.user` will return a single user object, namely the user that the post belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following:

```
@follow_links = FollowLink.where(:follow_you_id => @user.id)
@follow_links.collect(&:user) # :user should be the name of your relation to user in your followlink model
=> [User1, User2,...]
```

Comment: This is possible, but it will possibly generate A LOT of queries.